# Having problem to relaunch app on phone after killing it

Tags: android

I can run this perfectly fine on an AVD. I also can launch the app at the beginning via USB debugging on my Oppo A5 but then I tried to kill it and relaunch it again but it shows this error in the logcat :

```
2022-05-19 19:53:41.962 1685-1713/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2022-05-19 19:54:00.007 1685-1709/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2022-05-19 19:54:00.008 1685-1709/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
2022-05-19 19:54:00.010 1439-1467/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 4 syncs in 60s
```

So far I have tried kill adb-server and start it back and it was unsuccessful.

Comment: If you are using adb to re - launch the app kindly share the command you are using,

Comment: @TaranmeetSingh I have tried adb kill-server and adb start-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by updating to the latest version of Android Studio. However a new error came up as stated below :

```
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

I have also resolved the issue by adding addFlags just before starting an intent activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```